# Submit is not returning desired result in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, python-2.7

```
$('#submittask').on('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url: "/myapp/addTask/",
        data: $("#idForm").serialize(),
        success : function(response) { 
           $('#taskContainer').html(response);
        },

   });
});
```

Returns desire result. But if I do this:

```
$('#submittask').on('submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url: "/myapp/addTask/",
        data: $("#idForm").serialize(),
        success : function(response) { 
            $('#taskContainer').html(response);
        },

    });
});
```

doesn't return the desired result. Instead of returning the data in success it returns data to n new html page

Comment: What is different between both code?

Comment: Try once `$('#idForm').on('submit',function(event){` instead of `$('#submittask').on('submit',function(event){`

Comment: Remove comma (,) at end of success callback function.

Comment: I tried but doesn't work

Comment: @loncar Unless he's using an old IE version, you can have comma at the end of an object.

Comment: @Barmar it's not by the book, try something like this `var obj = { name : "", };` at [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/)

Comment: @loncar jslint does that because it breaks in old versions of IE. https://jslinterrors.com/extra-comma

Comment: @Barmar thanks for information, I have little bit paranoia about JS standards that was left when I was modifying some project to support IE6. :)

Comment: @loncar You have my sympathies :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to add submit event to a button? Submit event should be attached to a form and not a button.

Comment: I tried to submit form using submit button. But it doesn't work so, at last I made it button.

Comment: You can do something like this:   $('form').on('submit', function(){});